# Is it possible to highlight nonconsecutive words in any given text cell?

Tags: user-interface

This is a bit of a miscellaneous question, so I'm not entirely sure how to tag it properly.

Windows users can use the CTRL button (and Mac users, Command if I'm not mistaken) as a sort of hotkey to select several cells at a time:

[image]

to be able to select two non-adjacent cells and select an arbitrary formatting style to only apply to the two selected cells.

Is it possible to do something similar with text within any one cell? For example, I'd like to highlight/add background color to "Words" in the first cell and to "Even" and "words" in the third cell, but not "more" in either of the last two.

I could convert the text to a string and carry out some manipulations from there, but in practice I would be able to spend less time coming up with patterns to look for and instead eyeballing a block of text and skimming it for words with, say, letters possessing diacritics or words with hyphens.

Comment: Probably the only what you can do is to create a Palette with an `InputField` (where you'll input the text you wish to highlight) and some controls for setting the type of highlighting you want. You also can modify the default context menu of the `"Text`" cells and add there some commands which bring up the dialog asking your what to highlight and then perform this. Of course all this isn't very simple and straightforward.